# How to decompose a system into modules?

Tags: modularity

The effectiveness of a "modularization" is dependent upon the criteria used in dividing the system into modules.

What I want is, suggest some criteria which can be used in decomposing a system into modules.

Comment: A similar thread exist here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413247/what-are-the-best-resources-if-you-wanted-to-create-an-application-with-modulariz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)): the functionality in a module is related.

[Low coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_science)): you have minimum dependencies between modules.

Coordinated lifecycle: changes to functionality within a module tends to occur at the same time. Usually a consequence of high cohesion.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Single Responsibility Principle would be a good guide. Try to define responsibilities for each modules, and make each module be responsible for its own thing.

See http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod

Answer (score 1):

Interesting reading too: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Design/criteria.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It is a very old question.

- Module is a work assignment to a programmer or group of programmers. This also is the unit of change.
- Coupling and cohesion are metrics for estimation quality of relationships between modules but they are not useful for decomposition.
- The decomposition should be made using "[information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding)" as a criterion.
- Introduction with examples and description of process based on "information hiding" principle: http://www.sqrl.ul.ie/Downloads/Lecture2.pdf.
- State of art of this question is the software product line topic.